# Валидация времени ларавел

Tags: php, laravel

Как сделать валидацию времени типа H:i ?

Юзаю `date_format:H:i`

Но если прийдет символ вместо времени, например "ва:02", то получаю ошибку

> DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (ва:30) at
>   position 0 (�): Unexpected character

Есть идеи?

Comment: А нельзя регуляркой вырезать весь русский алфавит?

Comment: @СвободуСергеюСуровцеву ну тогда будет :02. Плюс, русский алфавит - это пример. Там может быть что угодно.

Comment: Используйте регулярку если не можете воспользоваться средствами Laravel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот простое выражение, которое я написал. Может кому то будет полезно

```
preg_match("/\d{2}:\d{2}/", $this->request->get('time'))
```

Проверяет строку вхождение на формат:

> [цифра][цифра]:[цифра][цифра]
>   , например время 09:35

Answer (score 0):

Все работает правильно 
У вас есть правило date_format:H:i и оно не пропускает ни чего лишнего.
Зачем вам обрабатывать невалидную строку "ва:02" ?

Comment: Затем, чтобы избежать ошибки, когда юзер захочет попробувать "А что будет если..."

Comment: если юзер хочет отправить неверные данные, серевер должен кму сообщить об этом. Думаю нужно просто настроить правильный ответ ошибок. У меня если нарушенна дата приходит ответ 422 и {
    "errors": {
        "code": "8",
        "message": "Атрибут date должен формата даты yyyy-mm-dd"
    }
}